# How to sync Android studio project between multiple computers

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a way to work on an Android studio project from multiple computers? Like so that my partner can work on one part of the app while I work on the other without having to like copy and paste and all that.

Comment: You can use version control tools

Comment: Use [Subversion](https://medium.com/indianic/importing-your-android-studio-project-in-svn-subversion-39db20e2a4cd).

Comment: You can use Git or SVN (version control tools). This will require a server both can access for the common repository. See bitbucket or github depending if you need it to be private or if it can be public

Answer (score 3):

There are so many option for doing this,
You can use version control for that

like, **Subversion** (SVN) : which manage code on your local server, and this is totally free.
like for more detail:

https://medium.com/indianic/importing-your-android-studio-project-in-svn-subversion-39db20e2a4cd

Another world widely famous option is **GitHub** : https://www.londonappdeveloper.com/how-to-use-git-hub-with-android-studio/

some another version control system is: [**Gitlab**](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/export-android-studio-project-to-gitlab/2656/4) &  **bitbucket**

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose best option is git, You have to read about git.

You can find very good tutorial [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Getting-Started)

For UI option for Git you can use [Sourcetree](https://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree)